# populating html forms with what the user had selected on last login

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a small user login script and once the user is logged in they are able to make a selection from 5-7 check-boxes.  I was wondering is possible to save the users selection so that next time they log in the the check-boxes they selected previously will be already selected? what would be the best way to go about this? maybe $session or maybe save it in a db?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes you can save the user selection in databases as per the user id and retrieve it as per your requirements

Comment: Best option is to save to database/table if settings are important.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, save the data on the **server** or save the data on the **client**:

## Server

Save data of selections on a table and server to the client with the selected values.

## Client

Use cookies to store the selections on the client.

However, if the user deletes de cookies will lose the information. And if the user does not have cookies activated, it will not work at all.